# How to control chapter headings in report documentclass

Tags: sectioning, report

I've been using Latex for a while but I'm now starting to write my thesis and I'm having trouble with the chapter headings.

I'm using the report documentclass as it allows my to use the \include command so I can have a file per chapter.

The issue I'm having is that I need to be able to control the chapter headings. I'd like to be able to get rid of the automatic "Chapter n" before the chapter title and the title also needs to be centered.

I've tried a few things but all of them seem to mean I have to change the documentclass and this is something I don't really want to do.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest that your reconsider your decision "not to change the documentclass". report is old and you will waste time to get around its problems. Use a modern class like scrreprt or memoir.

Comment: "change the documentclass" might mean "modify the code in the .cls file", in which case, I'd agree it's a bad idea. But yes, `memoir` definitely beats `report` on customization, as long as you have time to read through its documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you redefine the chapter headings using the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) 
package. It is very advanced, but it is easy to make your requested changes.

Alternatively, you can use the less advance [secsty](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package, but maybe you will not achieve your goal.

Another possibility is to replace your `report`-class with `scrreprt` from the [KOMA-script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)-bundle. KOMAscript is a drop-in replacement for the standard class, but with the possibility to change headings etc. easily.

And finally, you can redefine the report class definition. At [Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX) homepage, you will find necessary code, for [titles](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html), for [chapters](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and for [sections](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html).

Here is a modification of Zoonekynd's code that (hopefully) remove the word `Chapter`, put the number and the heading at the same line with a `quad` space in between, and then centre the heading. You have to modify the font size and space above and below yourself.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries \thechapter\quad #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
    %\vskip 40\p@
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
    \vskip 100\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

Test test
\end{document}
```