# Adjust the font size of the headings pagestyle

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, pagestyle

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62701/font-size-in-the-headings-pagestyle) question, I want to ensure the section titles fit within the header boundaries of my document. I'm using **KOMA scrreprt** as a document class.

To achieve this, I have reduced their font size as follows
`\renewcommand*\headfont{\normalfont\footnotesize}`
but it's not the solution I'm looking for, since I would like to keep the same font size over the document. Is it possible, e.g., to break the line just in the header? I appreciate any helps!

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=a4,
    twoside=true,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=notnumbered,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
    headings=normalsize,
    fontsize=12pt,
    chapterprefix=true,
]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{listof=entryprefix}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*\headfont{\normalfont\footnotesize} % My solution

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{Length of this section's title fits well}
\lipsum[1-8]
%\newpage
\section{Here the long section's title exceeds the boundaries of the A4 page in the header. I want to ensure the section titles fit within the header boundaries of my document.}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about an optional shorter section title just for the header line instead of a smaller font size? E.g. `\section[shorter version for the header]\section{Here the long section's title exceeds the boundaries of the A4 page in the header. I want to ensure the section titles fit within the header boundaries of my document.}` and the option `[headings=optiontohead]` for the document class?

Comment: Some AI tool suggested the same solution :)

Comment: Note: Redefining `\headfont` is deprecated. You should use the `\setkomafont`/`\addtokomafont` interface instead. Documentation of `\headfont` even has been removed from the KOMA-Script manuals years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `headings=optiontohead` and the optional argument to `\section`. I don't see why using `scrrreprt` instead of `scrbook`.

Also, use `\setkomafont{pagehead}` to (globally) change the size; I find it a good idea to have the headers in a smaller size than the text.

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=a4,
    twoside=true,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=notnumbered,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
    fontsize=12pt,
    chapterprefix=true,
    headings=optiontohead,
]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{listof=entryprefix}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalsize\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{Length of this section's title fits well}
\lipsum[1-8]

\section[Here the long section's title exceeds the boundaries of the A4 page in the header.]
  {Here the long section's title exceeds the boundaries of the A4 page in the header.
   I want to ensure the section titles fit within the header boundaries of my document.}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The title in the table of contents will be the long one.

[image]

Comment: I used `scrreprt` since I want to avoid those extra pages that are automatically included after the ToC as well as the LoF. However, I found your solution very helpful.

Comment: @Ian Use the `open=any` option.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend to use @egreg's answer. However, if you really, really want multi-line page headers, you can use package `scrlayer-scrpage` and also add class option `headlines=2` (to support 2 line of page header):

```latex
\documentclass[%
    paper=a4,            % default and therefore not needed
    twoside=true,
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=notnumbered,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    footsepline,
%    headings=normalsize,% Option headings does not provide an argument
%                        % normalsize. So it is unclear, what you wanted here!
    fontsize=12pt,
    chapterprefix=true,
    headlines=2,
]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{listof=entryprefix}% Why not addded to the options of \documentclass?
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % default since LaTeX 2018-04-01
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{Length of this section's title fits well}
\lipsum[1-8]
%\newpage
\section{Here the long section's title exceeds the boundaries of the A4 page in the header. I want to ensure the section titles fit within the header boundaries of my document.}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]